# Automatically resizing subview created programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nssplitview, bwtoolkit

I have a NSSplitView. On the left pane of that split view I have an NSTableView and a custom view created programmatically. I'm using a [delegate](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/nssplitview-delegate-for-priority-based.html) to make sure my two panes don't resize at the same time.

I add my custom view thus:

```
BWAnchoredButtonBar *anchoredButtonBar = [[[BWAnchoredButtonBar alloc] initWithFrame:[leftPane bounds]] autorelease];
[leftPane addSubview:anchoredButtonBar];
```

And it seems to work ok. When I run my application everything works fine. Now, my problem is that when I resize the split view pane, the custom view does not resize with it leaving an ugly white space between it and the divider of the NSSplitView.

I guess what I want to ask is, how can I programmatically set the springs and struts that IB sets visually?

Also, I can't use IB because Xcode 4 does not support IB plugins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`-[NSView setAutoresizingMask:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCEBCGI) is how you set springs and struts programmatically.